# QR code generated but it is not scannable - React Native

Tags: react-native

I have generated QR code using

> "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.1.2",
> "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",

Generated QR Code is like this,
[qr code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPMnF.jpg)

Not getting any result after scanning this.

This is the code,

```
<QRCode
  value="https://www.youtube.com/"
  size={width - 220}
  color='white'
  backgroundColor='black'
 ></QRCode>
```

Please someone help me to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to invert the colors and have a white border around the image, like this:

[image: Adjusted QR Code]

The border around the image should have at least the width of the QRCode's pixel, so if the smallest square inside the image has 8×8px, then the border should have at least 8px.

The color outside the border can be white too.

Comment: I have changed the code ,
<QRCode
  value="https://www.youtube.com/"
  size={width - 220}
  color='black'
  backgroundColor='white'
 ></QRCode>